# Code fails for large input (time taken >5 seconds)

Tags: string, python-3.x, for-loop, set

> The problem is as follows-Given a set of 26 coins labeled from a to
>   z,we need to find all those pairs(i,j) wherein i
>
> Sample input- 3 abcaa
>
> Sample Output- 5
>
> Explanation
>
> S[i:j] denotes the sequence Si,Si+1,....,Sj−1,Sj
>
> Since, K=3
>
> Possible pairs (i,j) such that number of distinct coins in S[i:j] is
>   exactly equal to K are:
>
> (1,3) and S[1:3]=abc (1,4) and S[1:4]=abca (1,5) and S[1:5]=abcaa
>   (2,4) and S[2:4]=bca (2,5) and S[2:5]=bcaa
>
> So the answer is 5
>
> Here is my code which is working for small input but fails for large
>   input(time taken >5 seconds)

```
k=int(input())
nex=[]
coin_sequence=list(input())
new=[]
master_count=0
count=0
for i in  range(0,len(coin_sequence)+1):
    for j in range(0,len(coin_sequence)+1):
        if(i<=j):
            nex=len(set(coin_sequence[i:j]))
            if nex==k:
                master_count=master_count+1

print(master_count)
```

Comment: `for j in range(0,len(coin_sequence)+1):
        if(i<=j):` => `for j in range(i,len(coin_sequence)+1):`. Not sure it's enough but you just some useless empty loops

Answer (score 0):

Small optimization:

```
rng=range(0, len(coin_sequence)+1)
for i in  rng:
    for j in rng:
        if(i<=j):
            nex=len(set(coin_sequence[i:j]))
            if nex==k:
                master_count=master_count+1

print(master_count)
```

Comment: There is no measurable difference in time taken,Any other ideas @Dominique Lorre?

Comment: What you need is a better mathematical solution. so try to ask one of the math exchanges.

Comment: How do i Do that?